# Bootstrap menu bug on desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The navigation on my desktop version looks fine when I remove the clear from the mobile version. But when I do, the collapsed menu on my mobile version is bugged. Yet I can't seem to set my clear to default in my media query. I've tried float and position:relative but nothing seems to work to get my brand and my navigation on the same line.

[image]

```
@media only screen and(min-width:786px){
.custom-navbar .navbar-collapse {
    clear:none;
}
```

**EDIT**: here's a minimal 'working' example: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojroJK)

Comment: Please post a minimal, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS). [mcve]

Comment: try `clear:initial !important;`

Comment: @vanburen I've added a 'working' example.

Comment: Your minimal 'working' link does not work.

Comment: @Alon I've tried, didn't work.

Comment: @alirezasafian It should work now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your HTML. You have your SVG as in lieu of a button, it should be place inside the toggle-button which is then inside the navbar-header, not after. Also, `navbar-right` belongs with the `ul`, not `navbar-collpase`.

See [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and working Snippet.

```css
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
.navbar.custom-navbar .navbar-nav li a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #DFBA68;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.navbar.custom-navbar {
  background-color: #252626;
}
.navbar.custom-navbar .navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'sharpie';
  color: #DFBA68;
}
.navbar.custom-navbar .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #DFBA68;
}
.navbar.custom-navbar .navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top custom-navbar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <svg height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <path d="M0,40C0,40,100,40,100,40C100,40,100,60,100,60C100,60,0,60,0,60" fill="#f7f4ea"></path>
          <path d="M0,20C0,20,100,20,100,20M100,80C100,80,0,80,0,80" stroke="#dfba68" style="stroke-width: 4px;"></path>
        </svg>
      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" title="Help">Hannelore Goovaerts.be</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `clear:both` from `.custom-navbar .navbar-collapse`. `clear:both;` force an element to be [placed in the new line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear) after the elements which have `float:right;` or `float:left;`.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/epwewP)

```
.custom-navbar .navbar-collapse {
    /* clear: both; */
    float: none;
}
```